# How to use stellar define a ERC721 like asset

Tags: assets

With the help of stellar, It's easy to issue and transfer asset like ERC20. But if we want to build some application based on stellar, for example, we are a handmade shoes shop, each shoes has different attributes, we give each shoes a QR code, how to define this kind of asset(shoes) in stellar?

Answer (score 2):

Here is *my* take on non-fungible tokens on Stellar,

https://github.com/future-tense/stellar-nft-issuer/

Comment: That's great, but if there is any performance issue with too many account in stellar, somebody has tested if there are more than 40k accounts, it will affect the performance. I'm thinking about one solution about one single product mapping to one asset. For example, product 3 shoes, issue 3 assets with code shoes00001, shoes0002, shoes0003.